# java.lang.verify error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I've added a few jars from the Factual API, my project builds fine, and the jars can be accessed from my main module. However, when I run the app I'm getting 'java.lang.verify' error as follows:

```
11-05 13:18:07.094    4612-4612/com.example.nickm.tddeals E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.VerifyError: com/factual/driver/Factual
        at com.example.nickm.tddeals.Map.onCreate(Map.java:38)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My main activity uses a google map (that is working without the Factual instantiation) and eventually attempts to instantiate a Factual object, where the error is thrown.

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.factual.driver.Factual;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class Map extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
private Factual factual;
private double myLatitude;
private double myLongitude;
private GPSService gpsService;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    updateLocation();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(gpsService.getLatitude(), gpsService.getLongitude());
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17);
    mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
    factual = new Factual("snip", "snip");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

/**
 * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
 * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
 * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
 * <p>
 * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
 * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
 * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
 * <p>
 * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
 * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
 * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
 * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
 * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
 */
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
 * just add a marker near Africa.
 * <p>
 * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
 */
private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
}

private void updateLocation(){
    gpsService = new GPSService(getApplicationContext());
    Location location = gpsService.getLocation();
    while(!gpsService.isLocationAvailable)
    {
        location = gpsService.getLocation();
    }
}
}
```

Main module gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.nickm.tddeals"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
compile project(':factual-java-driver-1.8.7')
compile project(':factual-java-driver-1.8.7-javadoc')
compile project(':factual-java-driver-1.8.7-sources')
}
```

Doing some searching on this error seems to bring up obscure answers. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never solved this specific bug, but a more outside the box solution was used:

- We didn't use the Factual API. We used Google Places instead.

Much easier to integrate with our app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Android version of the Factual SDK:

```
compile 'com.factual:factual-java-driver:1.8.2-android'
```

https://github.com/Factual/factual-java-driver/tree/master-android

The Factual java source or one of its dependencies likely targets a version of Java that is not supported on Android.

Comment: I'm now using the android driver and unfortunately still getting the same error. Is it possible that I need to add my jars into another folder of the project? Right now I have the Android jar only added as a module.